# Save Facebook information to MySQL

Tags: php, arrays, facebook, sdk

I need save Facebook information to MySQL table. I'm using PHP SDK for get data from users. When I get data these data are in associative array. I need parse this array to MySQL database.

```
    <?php
require '/src/facebook.php';

$dbname = '';
$dbpass = '';
$dbuser = '';
$dbhost = '';

$appId = '';
$secret = '';

mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
mysql_select_db($dbname);



$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId' => $appId,
  'secret' => $secret,

));

$user = $facebook->getUser();
$access_token = 'fb_'.$appId.'_access_token';


if ($user) {
  try {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
    array(
      'scope' => 'user_about_me,user_activities,user_birthday'  
      )
    );
}

$sql_insert = "INSERT INTO users (user_id,username,access_token) VALUES ('$user_profile[id]','$user_profile[username]','$_SESSION[$access_token]')";
$sql_select = "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_id='$user_profile[id]'";

$res = mysql_query($sql_select);

if(!mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) { mysql_query($sql_insert); } 

?>
```

This procedure return me

```
    Array
(
    [id] => 1088214852
    [name] => User Name
    [first_name] => User 
    [last_name] => Name
    [link] => http://www.facebook.com/user.name
    [username] => user.name
    [birthday] => 24/12/2011
    [hometown] => Array
        (
            [id] => 107833015912178
            [name] => NY
        )

    [location] => Array
        (
            [id] => 109589969066408
            [name] => CA
        )
```

This is only part of this array.

Comment: So you want someone to code you a parser :) ?

Comment: no, i need help how code parser ;)

Comment: This seems like a simple database usage problem. 1) Identify data to be captured (type of content - text/integer/boolean), 2) Build database, 3) Build Queries/Statements to interact with database, 4) Build PHP incorporating those statements, 5) ???, 6) Profit!!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10569922/facebook-php-sdk-store-user-data-into-mysql-database 
Here is answer for your question

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you may only store limited facebook user information in your database.  Please read Facebook's API Legal terms that you agreed to when you signed up as a developer.  If you breach that contract, Facebook will pull your privileges.