# redirected php page doesn't load unless I hit refresh

Tags: php, mysql, facebook

Good morning, I finally managed to store the Facebook usernames in my database after Facebook login. The only problem is that the page where the user is redirected to after Facebook login needs to be reloaded (I get just an empty page the first time). Can you please refer to my previous question as I've already posted the all code [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10569922/facebook-php-sdk-store-user-data-into-mysql-database/10569945#comment13684457_10569945)

UPDATE: I noticed that the page needs to be refreshed only the first time (when the user info are not yet stored in the database, then it's loads the page quick and nicely. PLEASE HELP!;-)

UPDATE2: is there a way to auto refresh the page (just once) after the new user has been added?
many Thanks!

UPDATE 3: I post the code.... it works only when i refresh the page.... any idea?

```
        <?php

          mysql_connect('host', 'username', 'password');  
           mysql_select_db('table');  



require 'library/facebook.php';

    // Create our Application instance 
   $facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => 'MYID',
   'secret' => 'MYSECRET',
  'cookie' => true));


// Get User ID
 $user = $facebook->getUser();



   if ($user) {
     try {
   // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
   $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');



   } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
   error_log($e);
   $user = null;
   }
     }else{
   header('location: index.php');

    }
      $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE oauth_provider = 'facebook' AND       oauth_uid = ". $user_profile['id']);  
      $result = mysql_fetch_array($query);  

    if(empty($result)){ 
      $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (oauth_provider, oauth_uid, username)         VALUES ('facebook', {$user_profile['id']}, '{$user_profile['name']}')");  
       $query = msyql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = " . mysql_insert_id());  
      $result = mysql_fetch_array($query);  

       }  



    if ($user) {
     $paramsout = array('next'=>'http://www.mywebsite/test/logout.php');
     $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl($paramsout);
     }


     ?>
```

UPDATE 4*****: I found a solution. You can look on my answer below. Thanks to everybody.

Comment: what do you want exactly  can you please elaborate

Comment: I want that my page doesn't need to be reloaded after the login. When the user is redirected from Facebook login to my page (user_page.php) I get an empty page with only the background-color of the body. I have to push the reload button to get the page loaded. I hope it's more clear now. I think the problem is caused by a wrong "position" of my database query in the code i'm not able to figure it out.

Comment: Your `user_page.php` code is not complete, what would happen if the user is already registered? nothing? also why asking for the user id twice `$fbuid = $facebook->getUser();`?

Comment: Thanks Ifaour.... I didn't notice i was asking twice until know....;-)

Comment: On refreshing the page (so that it actually loads), what is displayed?  I can't see anything that would be output there... do you want to logout users immediately after they've logged in?  :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally I made it. Of course it was a redirection problem. But it didn't work neither adding the sql in index.php nor in user_page.php.
I ended up crating "login.php" where the user is redirected from Facebook page, added to the database if it's a new record and then redirected to user_page.php. 
This is the code for login.php:

```
<?php


 mysql_connect('HOST', 'USER', 'PSW');  
 mysql_select_db('MYDATABASE');

 require 'library/facebook.php';

  // Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
   $facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'MYID',
  'secret' => 'MYSECRET',
   'cookie' => true));


// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if($user){

 $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE oauth_provider = 'facebook' AND oauth_uid = ". $user_profile['id']);
    $result = mysql_fetch_array($query);

    if(empty($result)){
        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (oauth_provider, oauth_uid, username) VALUES ('facebook', {$user_profile['id']}, '{$user_profile['name']}')");

        header('Location: user_page.php');
                                }else{
        header('Location: user_page.php');
         }


          }else{

        header('Location: logout.php');


        }


           ?>
```

Comment: Well, its almost the same what a few people asked to do; good to see its working now

Comment: It's what I was trying to do since the beginning and I don't understand why header was not working in the code I posted above. Thanks Junaid.

Comment: well, finally its working that's what was required :).. btw `header was not working` is another issue if it really was not working, it has lots of reason. and its another debate.

Comment: I've just started to "play" with php....I'm not surprised it was not working as expected!;-)

Answer (score 3):

when facebook redirects using next or redirect URL it send the post data which the api gets but when you manually redirects your page it don't gets the facebook post data hence the code in `else condition header('location: index.php');` is executed and you are redirected properly..

the problem for the first time is because it by passes the else condition and go to the sql to insert new record and after that their is no redirection.. so you need to put `header('location: index.php');` in the end to redirect it after user record insertion in the db

hope this helps

Comment: can you please Copy my code and past it in your answer putting header where you think it should be. thanks

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried putting the header after the sql but for some reason I still have to refresh the page. I understand that the code has to run the code twice: the first time to insert the new record and the second time to load the page. I'm sure there is something wrong in my if else condition but I can't figure out how to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
header("Location: url");
exit();
```

after all the necessary actions, assuming that you don't send any headers to this moment. Otherwise you may use META REFRESH or JS document.location.href in the resulting document.

Comment: I tried the header but I still need to hit the refresh button. I'll try meta refresh.

Comment: I tried... but it keep reloading and it's very annoying. There must be something more "clean" to let it work.

Comment: You don't have to put this tag every time. Use a variable like $bNeedsRefresh, set to FALSE by default. If you added a new user successfully, set this variable to TRUE. When producing page output, add this tag only if the variable is set to TRUE.

Answer (score 1):

I think you must update your script try to load or fetch $user profile instead of loading just user .. may be it works

Comment: I think that part works fine. I'm able to add users in my database. The only problem is that I need to refresh the page anytime a new user logs in.

Answer (score 1):

You maybe need to add `header("Location: $url");` in the end of your script.

Comment: What does *doesn't work* mean? Have you done a redirection before this one?

Comment: I think The problem may be That i didn't Put The redirection at The end....i'll try to change That....

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'lib/facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php';

define('APP_TITLE', 'Cool project');
define('APP_DESCRIPTION', 'Very nice project');
define('APP_ID', '168565339939940');
define('APP_SECRET', '4127eee9d3ab29a114e80h89060243a7');
define('APP_URL', 'https://localhost/project/');
define('APP_PERMISSIONS', '');

$user_id = null;
$user_profile = null;

$fb = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => APP_ID,
    'secret' => APP_SECRET,
    'cookie' => true,
));

$loginUrlParams = array(
  'scope' => APP_PERMISSIONS,
  'redirect_uri' => APP_URL,
);

$user_id = $fb->getUser();

if ( $user_id ) 
{
    try 
    {
        $data = $fb->api('/me');

        $user_profile = array(
            'user_id' => $user_id,
            'name' => isset($data['name']) ? he($data['name']) : null,
            'avatar' => 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$user_id.'/picture',
        );

        unset($data);
    } 
    catch ( FacebookApiException $e ) 
    {
        header('Location: ' . $fb->getLoginUrl($loginUrlParams));
        exit;
    }
}
else
{
    header('Location: ' . $fb->getLoginUrl($loginUrlParams));
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or else use javascript or jquery that will tell you at run time you dont have to redirect